# Remove headerPanel entry from csv downloadable (Rshiny, extensions, buttons)

Tags: csv, button, shiny, copy, dt

Considering the following simple Rshiny app,

```
ui <-shinyUI(fluidPage(
  headerPanel("test"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("tab"),
))

server <- function (input, output) {
  output$tab <- DT::renderDataTable(
    iris, extensions = 'Buttons', rownames = FALSE,
    options = list(
      dom = 'frtBip',
      buttons = list('copy', list(extend = 'csv', filename= 'test'))
    )
  )
  observeEvent(input$tab_rows_selected,{
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

How can I ignore the `headerPanel` entry so it is not considered for the `copy` button? Ideally this means erasing the first two rows of information (I copied the output into a csv file for visualization purposes).

[image]

For the `csv` button I managed (by coincidence) to achieve the task above by using `rownames = FALSE`. Can anyone also please explain why that worked? I do not really follow the connection. Below I attach a screenshot of the output obtained by using the `csv` button.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
      buttons = list(
        list(extend = 'copy', text = 'Copy', title = NULL), 
        list(extend = 'csv', filename= 'test')
      )
```